# System.getenv() cannot get override parameter which is set in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables

I set one environment in IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug configuration as below:

[image]

I am trying to get the environment value while the code is running, but it returns `null`:

[image]

Why does not it return `cfc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation for Spring Boot Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#e2d25c1e) describes the **Override parameters** are used for:

> Use this table to specify Spring Boot configuration parameters that you want to override. Such parameters are normally defined in configuration files.

To define OS environment variables use **Environment variables** box.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. By the way, the pictures I attached in the post is down. I don't know why...